# How to use view-source to find function in codebase

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, web-development-server

I'm new to both PHP and CodeIgniter, and web dev in general.  I'm stepping into an already established codebase and being asked to make some changes.  Is there a way to find functionality in the codebase based on a URL that I see when I inspect an element from the browser?

[image: Screenshot]

For the above, I would like to find where the logic to add a new entry is to the database.  I tried searching all files for "new_entry" but nothing comes up.  Also, there does not seem to be a folder called "db" so I'm just a bit lost on where to look.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look through the routes to see where the controller for that lives. Also check your server logs to see what comes up.

Comment: in addition of finding the correct routing in config/routes.php, the general anatomy of CI url is explained here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

you can user uri segment on codeigniter

```
$this->uri->segment('2')
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, your controller file with functions for this example should be in `application>controllers>db.php`

In this file there should be function named: "new_entry" accepting one argument with is probably string "song" in this situation.

Another possibility may be, that a cantroller is named "new_entry" and it might be stred in `application>controllers>db>new_entry.php`